# Is it practical to use pymongo as JSON search tool?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, search, pymongo

I need to get elements from a json by there attributs. So exactly what the find_one() funktion of pymongo would do. In the end I don't need and want the JSON-file I want to edit in a database. So my idea to avoid to loop trough the JSON-file is to load the json into a local Mongo database, find and edit my elements and the export and delete it from the MongoDB.

So the question is if it is more efficient to import, find and delte a json in pymongo then just looping through the json until a specific element?